# how do i copy an ad user through powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to copy an existing user, to a new user with a new name etc..

```
$root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$root.SearchRoot = "LDAP://dc=organization,dc=net"
$root.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=TestUser1))"
$result = $root.FindOne()

$test = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
$newparent = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($test.Parent)
$test.CopyTo($newparent,"TestUser2")
```

Whenever I run the code above, I keep getting:

```
ERROR: Exception calling "CopyTo" with "2" argument(s): "Not implemented
ERROR: "
TestDir.ps1 (22): ERROR: At Line: 22 char: 13
ERROR: + $test.CopyTo <<<< ($newparent,"TestUser2")
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
ERROR:
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I know what I'm trying to achieve exists in the ActiveDirectory module and in Quest.. but I do not have access to these so therefore I have to write this from scratch..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **instance** attribute with the **[New-AdUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852238.aspx)** method:

> ### [New-AdUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852238.aspx)
>
> Use a template to create the new object. To do this, create a new user object or retrieve a copy of an existing user object and set the Instance parameter to this object. The object provided to the Instance parameter is used as a template for the new object. You can override property values from the template by setting cmdlet parameters. For examples and more information, see the Instance parameter description for this cmdlet.
>
> #### `-Instance<ADUser>`
>
> Specifies an instance of a user object to use as a template for a new user object.
>   You can use an instance of an existing user object as a template or you can construct a new user object for template use. You can construct a new user object using the Windows PowerShell command line or by using a script.
>
> - **Method 1:** Use an existing user object as a template for a new object. To retrieve an instance of an existing user object, use a cmdlet such as Get-ADUser. Then provide this object to the Instance parameter of the New-ADUser cmdlet to create a new user object. You can override property values of the new object by setting the appropriate parameters.
> - **Method 2:** Create a new ADUser object and set the property values by using the Windows PowerShell command line interface. Then pass this object to the Instance parameter of the New-ADUser cmdlet to create the new Active Directory user object.

An example could be seen in a [support post on Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/fdf460aa-e00f-4ffe-8d38-ad08590c95e4/help-creating-new-ad-user-in-powershell-from-existing-user?forum=ITCG), in which the author can successfully create the user, but is having difficulties with the location of the new user object. I think you should read the post for a better understanding of the **New-AdUser** method and usage.

> `New-ADUser -SamAccountName "garyoj" -name "garyoj" -Instance $userinstance -PasswordNotRequire`

Comment: as i wrote in the original post, i do not have access to activedirectory module, so i am looking for how to do this with the directoryservices. thx

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll look into it